# How to mass update records while importing a workbook?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel source workbook and I have some people that sent me other workbooks with information so I can add this info to the source workbook.

I want to know if it's possible to import these workbooks into the Source Workbook so that my records automatically update and the records that are new be added to the Source Workbook

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you get all the files in the folder. which in your case would be the additional workbooks added.

```
Dim MyObject As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim mySource As Folder
Dim myFile As Scripting.File
dim strFolder as string
strFolder = 'you folder path

dim strFilePath as string
Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(strFolder)
For Each myFile In mySource.Files
    strFilePath = myFile.Path
   Next
```

Once you have file paths you use this code to open to the workbooks

```
dim wrkBook as workbook
set wrkbook = workbooks.open(strFilePath)
```

Once you've opened the workbooks the rest is pretty much straight forward

```
youVariable = wrkbook.worksheet(1).cells(i, j)
```